# How to position a line below a group of tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I am trying to position a horizontal line under a group of tags on an app done on asp.net mvc. I believe I have to do that on the CSS but I just can't seem to find the right way to place such line. 
Every time I try, the line ends up at the right of the tags and I don't feel like using a whole bunch of 
 is the right way by far.

```
<div id="section">
    <div style="float:left; margin:20px">
        <img alt="Upload" src="/Content/Images/Upload_yellow.png"/>
        <img alt="Confirm" src="/Content/Images/Confirm_white.png"/>
        <img alt="Review" src="/Content/Images/Review_white.png"/>
    </div>
    <hr />

</div>
```

Can somebody orient me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ditch the `<hr />` and add this change your CSS rule to `<div style="float:left; margin: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">`

If you have multiple floated divs in the section div, put the border rule on that if you want it to extend all the way across and set either `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto` so it doesn't collapse (which containers do when they only contain floated elements unless overflow is set). This way you can avoid setting a `clear` rule or adding extra markup for the line.

Comment: This is a really good solution, the problem is that I am not trying to underline only the tags. I need the line to go all the way accross.

Answer (score 2):

```
<hr style="clear: left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff and Joel [talked about this in Podcast #4](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-4/).  Specifically, the CSS-extremists would prefer you do that in CSS, but practical concerns override that. Keep it where it is now.